# Fewest polyominoes to construct digits

Tags: optimization, polyomino

What is the fewest polyominoes you need so that any one of the numbers $0$ to $9$ can be constructed?

[image]

When constructing, polyominoes may be rotated and flipped, but may not overlap.

Bonus: How few would you need if overlapping was allowed?

Comment: We're allowed to mix sizes? E.g. the answer might be something like "this domino, these two trominoes, and this tetromino"?

Comment: Sure, all polyominoes are allowed.

Comment: I read it as polynomials and was expecting a math question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Non-overlapping

It can be done using

> 5 polyominoes: two dominoes, one straight tromino, and two L-tetrominoes.

As follows:

> [image]
>
>  (dominoes in red and orange, tromino in the original green, tetrominoes in dark blue and light blue).

Proof that this is minimal:

> The number of squares in each digit is respectively 12, 5, 11, 11, 9, 11, 12, 7, 13, 10. Let's assume we can use just 4 polyominoes.
>
>  If we use anything bigger than a pentomino (a polyomino of 6 or more squares), then it's impossible: we can't even find four numbers $a,b,c,d$, one of them at least 6, which can be used to make sums that come to each of $5,7,9,10,11,12,13$. (This is by trial and error, but you can see that it's true by trying to mess around with the numbers.)
>
>  In fact, the same is true even if we use a pentomino: the best we can get is $a,b,c,d=2,3,4,5$, which gives us sums for all the numbers except $13$. ($2,3,3,5$ wouldn't give $9$; $2,4,4,5$ wouldn't give $12$; $2,2,4,5$ wouldn't give $10$; and so on.) So we must use only tetrominoes at largest.
>
>  Now how do we cover the digit 1? It must be with a **domino** and a **straight tromino**. So we have $a,b,c,d\leq4$ with $a=2$ and $b=3$; to be able to sum to $13$, we must have $c=d=4$, i.e. **two tetrominoes**. But using the numbers $2,3,4,4$ we can't get a sum of $12$. Contradiction!

### Overlapping

It can be done using

> 3 polyominoes, as shown in Glorfindel's answer.

Proof that this is minimal:

> Imagine it can be done with just 2 polyominoes. Then at least one of them must be straight, to cover the digit 1. The remainder of the digit 8 must be covered by a single M-shaped polyomino, which is not going to be useful in covering the digit 0. Contradiction.

Comment: Good arguments! Checkmark for you. :)

Comment: @Jens It was easier than I expected to prove that these numbers are minimal. Nice puzzle! Makes polyomino things a bit less daunting for me :-)

Answer (score 10):

A quick attempt using

> 5

polyominoes:

> [image]

---

Here is an attempt for the bonus question using

> 3

polyomnioes

> [image]
>  (yellow is placed first, then green, then red)

Comment: +1 You were first, but Rand also provided arguments for the answers, so on balance I gave him the checkmark.

Comment: No problem, his answer is indeed a bit better. I didn't have time to prove it formally.

Answer (score 4):

Non-overlapping:

> **5**
>
> ```
>  1, 22, 333, 444, 55
>              4    5
>
>  355    3    444   444   4 3
>  3 5    3      4     4   4 3
>  3 4    3    333   333   443
>  2 4    2    5       5     2
>  244    2    551   155     2
>
>
>  444   444   444   333   444
>  4     4       4   5 1   4 1
>  333   333     3   554   333
>    5   5 2     3   2 4     2
>  155   552     3   244     2
> ```